# WebGL readpixel working in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, three.js, webgl

Hi I am using following webgl script to read from render object, this works in chrome but gives "Error: WebGL: readPixels: Invalid type floatness" in firefox and IE

Code snippet:

```
    var gl = this.renderer.getContext();
    var pixels = new Uint8Array(this.net.RESOLUTION * this.net.RESOLUTION * 4);
    gl.readPixels(0, 0, this.net.RESOLUTION, this.net.RESOLUTION, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

Thanks in advance
Siddharth

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in

```
var renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(width, height, {
            wrapS : THREE.RepeatWrapping,
            wrapT : THREE.RepeatWrapping,
            minFilter : THREE.NearestFilter,
            magFilter : THREE.NearestFilter,
            format : type,
            type : THREE.FloatType,
            stencilBuffer : false
        });
```

Here type : THREE.FloatType is allowed in chrome but not in firefox !
So working WebGlRenderTarget is

```
        var renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(width, height, {
            wrapS : THREE.RepeatWrapping,
            wrapT : THREE.RepeatWrapping,
            minFilter : THREE.NearestFilter,
            magFilter : THREE.NearestFilter,
            format : type,
            stencilBuffer : false
        });
```